# Negating two verbs separated by or

Tags: negation, phrasing, phrase-usage

I'm curious about the logical implications of phrasings of the form:

```
not given or received
```

In my mind, this can parse as either "not (given or received)" or "(not given) or (received)", which clearly differ in meaning.

My theory is to prefer the second interpretation, as the first can be expressed more unambiguously by: "neither given nor received".

Is there an official ruling on this?

Comment: Your logic is perfectly reasonable—except the part where you implicitly expect millions of English speakers to frame their wording on the basis of what is most logical. I dare say that a very large proportion of English speakers would not be dissuaded from saying "not given or received" when they mean "neither given nor received" because they could say the latter and be unambiguous. Further, I suspect that I've been among those people from time to time. So as long as you're just working out how to say things clearly yourself, good for you—but beware of assuming that other people do the same.

Comment: The principle you are getting at is Grice's maximum of quantity. Someone says "Thomas jumped off of a cliff and died", and you assume that he died from the fall, because if he died in some other less obvious way the speaker would have said so. In this case to interpret the expression you assume that the speaker is not being intentionally ambiguous (maximum of manner), and that if they meant an unusual meaning they would have used more words to say it. So you are on the right track, except that, as @SvenYargs points out, the you have resolved the ambiguity with the less common meaning.

Comment: I think the word you want is *maxim*, not maximum.

Comment: @nighthawk... how would you parse "the car was not red or green"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in formal boolean logic the "not" operator would have a higher precedence than the "or" operator, so in this case:

"not given or received" = "(not given) or received".

In natural language English, no such formal precedence rules exist, so the statement is truly ambiguous. It is for this reason that the preferred form is :

"neither given nor received" or "either received or not given", depending on the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In the posted question, the poster reasons that "(not given) or (received)" is preferable to "not (given or received)" as an interpretation of "not given or received"—because a person who means "not (given or received)" could instead say "neither given nor received" and be unambiguous.

But you could flip this argument around and say that "not given or received" is likelier to mean "not (given or received)" than "(not given) or (received)" because a person who means the latter could instead say "either was not given or was received" and be unambiguous.

In interpreting the meaning of phrases that, in isolation, support multiple interpretations, we have to rely on the context in which they appear, and on the relative likelihood (based on general usage) that a particular meaning is intended. At a guess, I would say that most people who use the phrase "not given or received" mean "not (given or received)" rather than "(not given) or (received)"; but I suspect that it would take considerable research to corroborate or discredit that impression.